# Vue.js 2.0 data binding issue - one data field's change will trigger the other data fields' filter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Following is the code, I define a my data in Vue as below:

```
{
    result: {
      name: 'user A',
      age: 20,
      male: true
    },
    showDetails: true
  }
```

There are several filter/computed/methods in the view will do the result formatting.

The problem is even I just change the value of the **showDetailds**, the methods and filters defined for the **result** will be triggered as well.

May I know any issue in my code ? Or it's the natural of Vue.js (I don't believe.) ?

```js
function countTheCall(key) {
  let counter = document.getElementById(key)
  if (!counter) {
    let container = document.getElementById('statList')
    var item = document.createElement('li')
    item.innerHTML = `${key}: <span id='${key}'>0</span>`
    container.appendChild(item)
    counter = document.getElementById(key)
  }
  counter.innerText = _.parseInt(counter.innerText) + 1
}

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      result: {
        name: 'user A',
        age: 20,
        male: true
      },
      showDetails: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    countTheCall: function(key) {
      let counter = document.getElementById(key)
      counter.innerText = _.parseInt(counter.innerText) + 1
    },
    trimValue: function(value) {
      console.log('Invoke method - trimValue.')
      countTheCall('methodCalls of trimValue')
      return _.trim(value)
    },
    getValFromResult: function(key) {
      console.log('Invoke method - getValFromResult.')
      countTheCall('methodCalls of getValFromResult')
      return _.get(this.result, key, 'null')
    }
  },
  computed: {
    displayName: function() {
      console.log('Invoke computed value - computedVal.')
      countTheCall('computedCalls of displayName')
      return `${this.result.name} (${this.result.age})`
    }
  },
  filters: {
    convertString: function(val) {
      countTheCall('filterCalls of convertString')
      return _.upperFirst(val)
    },
    getValFromObject: function(obj, key) {
      console.log(`[filter] getValue From Object by ${key}`)
      countTheCall('filterCalls of getValFromObject')
      return _.get(obj, key, 'null')
    },
    convertDateString: function(datestr, format = 'MMM DD (ddd), YYYY') {
      console.log(`[filter] convertDateString ${datestr}`)
      countTheCall('filterCalls of convertDateString')
      let m = moment(datestr)
      let formattedStr = ''
      if (m.isValid()) {
        formattedStr = m.format(format)
      }
      return formattedStr
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

label {
  font-style: italic;
  color: black;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkblue;
}

.callStat {
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  border: solid darkgrey 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.bootcss.com/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.bootcss.com/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>


  <div class="callStat">
    <h4>The Stat. of Calls</h4>
    <ul id="statList"></ul>
  </div>
  <div id="app">
    <h2>User Profile</h2>
    <div>
      <label>User Name:</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="result.name"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Show Details:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="showDetails" v-model="showDetails"></input>
      <label for="showDetails">show detail section?</label>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div>
      <label>User Name:</label>
      <ul>
        <li>result.name: <span>{{trimValue(result.name)}}</span></li>
        <li>result.unknownFiled: <span>{{result.unknownFiled}}</span></li>
        <li>getValFromResult('name'): <span>{{ getValFromResult('name')}} </span></li>
        <li>getValFromResult('unknownField'): <span>{{ getValFromResult('unknownField')}} </span></li>
        <li>computed Display Name : <span>{{ displayName }} </span></li>
        <li>convertString by filter : <span>{{ result.name | convertString }} </span></li>
        <li>user birthDay: <span>{{ result.birthDay | convertDateString}}</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is natural to Vue.

Methods & Filters run on every DOM re-render.

This is why it's best to use Computed whenever possible - these re-run only on change of connected properties.